# Magento Layred Navigation not appearing in my custom list.phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have a custom list.phtml page. I have copied list.phtml page and rename it to newlist.phtml page. The only difference is I have changed the

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

TO

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => 2))
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
```

And using it by Adding the below in admin content

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/newlist.phtml"}}
```

AND below in layout update

```
<reference name="left">

    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav"  template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>

    </reference>
```

But this page does not showing the Layred Nav. But all other page like category pages shows the layred nav. Any idea???

Answer (score 1):

Layered navigation filters are working with `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')` object. You are directly finding product collection from catalog model object and this is causing issues here.

See Magento's product collection fetching logic here:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

Refer- app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your response. As I am just entered into magento world. So could you please tell what should I do to display the Layred Nav? Thanks in advance